# Is there a way to access slot in Svelte component created using Client-side component API?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am creating a svelte component in use:action function and I need to get add dynamic content inside the component. Does svelte allow to replace slot during or after creation of a svelte component?

Example code

```
export default function (node: HTMLElement) {
  let component = new Component({
      props: {},
      target: node,
      // maybe this
      slot: anotherComponent,
  });

  // or this
  component.slot = anotherComponent;

  return {
    update() {},
    destroy() {
      component.$destroy();
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Independent of the question and out of curiosity ~ what's a reason/usecase to do this via the action and not like this? https://svelte.dev/repl/b256900cd71946268a855c3b1d385d01?version=3.48.0

Comment: cause I want to make it clean up the code using actions and also the target is different, so  can't actually use it in a svelte component.

Answer (score 2):

That is [currently not supported](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2588), though that is a popular feature request. As noted in the issue, you can use private APIs at the peril of them breaking at any point.

You might be able to work around this by exposing an element of the component and mounting the child component there.

Comment: That is very ugly and defeats the purpose of having slots. Looking forward to the feature being supported in svelte.